# Php executing file from cli then running a cli command from file?

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to run a php built it server from the command line and I know  how to execute files from the command line, but what if i want to run a file from php command line interface and run php built-in server from the code inside the file executed by php cli.

Is it possible. If yes, how?

If no, Then how does the laravel runs the php builtin server by artisan command.

Comment: Have you looked into the shell_exec() command? Check out the documentation for that.

Comment: @jase thank you  exactly want i was looking for

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to executing commandline programs from PHP. There are shell_exec and proc_open. shell_exec is the easiest one of them both.

```
<?php
  echo shell_exec("whois domain.com"); 
?>
```

which will output the result from the whois command.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php